# Issue with IAP on Unity Android

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Purchases work perfectly on iOS, but on Android they fail.

It doesn't find the product:

04-30 10:39:41.446 14204-14232/? I/Unity: BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase

Here you can find the full log, many thanks in advance:

Purchases work perfectly on iOS, but on Android they fail.

It doesn't find the product:

04-30 10:39:41.446 14204-14232/? I/Unity: BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase

Here you can find the full log, many thanks in advance:

```
04-30 10:37:40.316 18708-18738/? I/Icing: Indexing done F90BEF8F9A0889CFF50102864CA085D2D06C7EC6



  --------- beginning of system

04-30 10:37:47.533 799-1305/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.[companyName].[appName] cmp=com.[companyName].[appName]/.UnityPlayerActivity} from uid 10016 on display 0

04-30 10:37:47.593 799-1969/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 14204:com.[companyName].[appName]/u0a231 for activity com.[companyName].[appName]/.UnityPlayerActivity

04-30 10:37:47.601 11733-11733/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.bd.d(507): Package first launch for com.[companyName].[appName]

04-30 10:37:47.606 11733-11733/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.bc.run(2391): Suppress referrer timestamp for com.[companyName].[appName]

04-30 10:37:47.606 11733-11733/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.bc.run(2452): Referrer is empty for com.[companyName].[appName]

04-30 10:37:47.607 11733-11733/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.bc.run(2453): Dropped referrer for com.[companyName].[appName] because unknown

04-30 10:37:47.634 799-1305/? I/ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {1.0 310mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w592dp h336dp 480dpi nrml land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.56}

04-30 10:37:47.639 799-891/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004

04-30 10:37:47.639 799-891/? I/InputReader: Device reconfigured: id=4, name='touch_dev', size 1080x1920, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0

04-30 10:37:47.696 11733-11871/? D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x941dfb80 (LayerDrawable) with handle 0x9c08a820

04-30 10:37:47.785 14204-14233/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

04-30 10:37:47.842 14204-14233/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb

04-30 10:37:47.855 14204-14233/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

04-30 10:37:47.917 799-817/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: On entry to LockedInner, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x1

04-30 10:37:47.917 799-817/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: after finishPostLayoutPolicyLw, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x0

04-30 10:37:47.918 799-817/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: mLayoutNeeded, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x1

04-30 10:37:47.919 799-817/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: On entry to LockedInner, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x1

04-30 10:37:47.919 799-817/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: after finishPostLayoutPolicyLw, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x0

04-30 10:37:47.919 799-817/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: mLayoutNeeded, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x1

04-30 10:37:47.920 799-817/? E/WindowManager: Performed 6 layouts in a row. Skipping

04-30 10:37:47.924 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()

04-30 10:37:47.930 799-817/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.[companyName].[appName]/.UnityPlayerActivity: +348ms

04-30 10:37:47.934 799-1234/? I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@42c24a<native proxy object> req=1flags=0x0

04-30 10:37:47.955 11733-11733/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.df.onTrimMemory(25): Memory trim requested to level 20

04-30 10:37:47.982 799-817/? I/WindowManager: Screen frozen for +368ms due to Window{6401267 u0 Starting com.[companyName].[appName]}

04-30 10:37:48.063 14204-14232/? W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateContext:2469>: EGL_BAD_MATCH

04-30 10:37:48.064 14204-14232/? W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:607>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE

04-30 10:37:48.064 14204-14232/? W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:607>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE

04-30 10:37:48.098 14204-14232/? D/Unity:  GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT

04-30 10:37:48.098 14204-14232/? D/Unity: _texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query

04-30 10:37:48.170 14204-14232/? W/libc: pthread_create sched_setscheduler call failed: Operation not permitted

04-30 10:37:48.176 196-786/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2

04-30 10:37:48.187 196-786/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)

04-30 10:37:48.187 196-786/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)

04-30 10:37:48.187 196-786/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)

04-30 10:37:48.190 196-786/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback

04-30 10:37:48.600 1324-1324/? W/RecentsTaskLoader: Missing ActivityInfo for ComponentInfo{com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.nodex.startup.splashscreen.NodexSplashActivity} u=0

04-30 10:37:49.994 799-817/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit

04-30 10:37:50.083 799-817/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 33764(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(292KB) LOS objects, 32% free, 33MB/49MB, paused 1.128ms total 79.408ms

04-30 10:37:53.986 799-810/? W/SensorService: sensor 00000000 already enabled in connection 0x89638c00 (ignoring)

04-30 10:37:54.281 14204-14232/? I/UnityIAP: IAB helper created.

04-30 10:37:54.417 14204-14232/? I/UnityIAP: Starting in-app billing setup.

04-30 10:37:54.419 14204-14204/? I/UnityIAP: Billing service connected.

04-30 10:37:54.420 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: invoking callback

04-30 10:37:54.421 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Checking for in-app billing 3 support.

04-30 10:37:54.422 11733-11876/? I/Finsky: [8087] com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.o.a(5172): com.[companyName].[appName]: Account determined from installer data - [wXIc8FFKawFiQJwwOOJ-1Bm5L-w]

04-30 10:37:54.423 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: In-app billing version 3 supported for com.[companyName].[appName]

04-30 10:37:54.424 11733-11744/? I/Finsky: [8061] com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.o.a(5172): com.[companyName].[appName]: Account determined from installer data - [wXIc8FFKawFiQJwwOOJ-1Bm5L-w]

04-30 10:37:54.424 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Subscriptions AVAILABLE.

04-30 10:37:54.425 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: onIabSetupFinished: 0

04-30 10:37:54.425 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Requesting 9 products

04-30 10:37:54.425 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: QueryInventory: 9

04-30 10:37:54.425 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: invoking callback

04-30 10:37:54.425 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Querying owned items, item type: inapp

04-30 10:37:54.425 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Package name: com.[companyName].[appName]

04-30 10:37:54.425 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null

04-30 10:37:54.427 11733-11743/? I/Finsky: [8060] com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.o.a(5172): com.[companyName].[appName]: Account determined from installer data - [wXIc8FFKawFiQJwwOOJ-1Bm5L-w]

04-30 10:37:54.427 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Owned items response: 0

04-30 10:37:54.427 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Continuation token: null

04-30 10:37:54.427 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Querying SKU details.

04-30 10:37:54.429 11733-11876/? I/Finsky: [8087] com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.o.a(5172): com.[companyName].[appName]: Account determined from installer data - [wXIc8FFKawFiQJwwOOJ-1Bm5L-w]

04-30 10:37:54.434 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].unlockalllevels","type":"inapp","price":"$39.99","price_amount_micros":39990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"Unlock All Levels ([appName])","description":"Unlock All Levels"}

04-30 10:37:54.434 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].unlocklevel1","type":"inapp","price":"$4.99","price_amount_micros":4990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"Unlock Level 1 ([appName])","description":"Unlock Level 1"}

04-30 10:37:54.434 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].unlocklevel2","type":"inapp","price":"$4.99","price_amount_micros":4990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"Unlock Level 2 ([appName])","description":"Unlock Level 2"}

04-30 10:37:54.434 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].unlocklevel3","type":"inapp","price":"$4.99","price_amount_micros":4990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"Unlock Level 3 ([appName])","description":"Unlock Level 3"}

04-30 10:37:54.434 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].unlocklevel4","type":"inapp","price":"$4.99","price_amount_micros":4990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"Unlock Level 4 ([appName])","description":"Unlock Level 4"}

04-30 10:37:54.435 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].unlocklevel5","type":"inapp","price":"$4.99","price_amount_micros":4990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"Unlock Level 5 ([appName])","description":"Unlock Level 5"}

04-30 10:37:54.435 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].unlocklevel6","type":"inapp","price":"$4.99","price_amount_micros":4990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"Unlock Level 6 ([appName])","description":"Unlock Level 6"}

04-30 10:37:54.435 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].unlocklevel7","type":"inapp","price":"$4.99","price_amount_micros":4990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"Unlock Level 7 ([appName])","description":"Unlock Level 7"}

04-30 10:37:54.435 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Querying owned items, item type: subs

04-30 10:37:54.435 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Package name: com.[companyName].[appName]

04-30 10:37:54.435 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null

04-30 10:37:54.436 11733-11744/? I/Finsky: [8061] com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.o.a(5172): com.[companyName].[appName]: Account determined from installer data - [wXIc8FFKawFiQJwwOOJ-1Bm5L-w]

04-30 10:37:54.437 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Owned items response: 0

04-30 10:37:54.437 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Continuation token: null

04-30 10:37:54.437 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Querying SKU details.

04-30 10:37:54.439 11733-11743/? I/Finsky: [8060] com.google.android.finsky.billing.iab.o.a(5172): com.[companyName].[appName]: Account determined from installer data - [wXIc8FFKawFiQJwwOOJ-1Bm5L-w]

04-30 10:37:54.447 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[appName].monthlysubscription","type":"subs","price":"$6.99","price_amount_micros":6990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"[appName] Monthly Subscription ([appName])","description":"[appName] Monthly Subscription"}

04-30 10:37:54.447 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: onQueryInventoryFinished: true

04-30 10:37:54.447 14204-14303/? I/UnityIAP: Inventory refresh successful. (response: 0:OK)

04-30 10:37:54.526 14204-14232/? I/Unity: [IAP] OnInitialized: PASS



   (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

04-30 10:37:54.750 14204-14232/? I/Unity: Download path set to http://s3.amazonaws.com/products.[companyName].com/[appName]/AssetBundles/Android/fullbundle



  (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

04-30 10:38:05.223 11733-11801/? I/Finsky: [8080] com.google.android.finsky.c.e.run(1151): Replicating app states via AMAS.

04-30 10:38:05.230 11733-14335/? I/Finsky: [8117] com.google.android.finsky.receivers.FlushLogsReceiver$FlushLogsService.onHandleIntent(162): Flushing event logs for [wXIc8FFKawFiQJwwOOJ-1Bm5L-w]

04-30 10:38:05.238 11733-11799/? I/PlayCommon: [8078] com.google.android.play.a.v.a(25540): Starting to flush logs

04-30 10:38:05.260 2173-2173/? V/GLSActivity: AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }

04-30 10:38:05.265 2173-2173/? V/GLSActivity: AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }

04-30 10:38:05.268 2173-2173/? V/GLSActivity: AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }

04-30 10:38:05.411 2173-2173/? V/GLSActivity: AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }

04-30 10:38:05.761 11733-11733/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.c.c.a(311): Completed 1 account content syncs with 1 successful.

04-30 10:38:05.763 11733-11733/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.services.j.a(149): Installation state replication succeeded.

04-30 10:38:05.881 11733-11799/? I/PlayCommon: [8078] com.google.android.play.a.v.a(25551): Log flushed by 1 successful uploads

04-30 10:38:06.046 18708-14350/? I/EventLogService: Opted in for usage reporting

04-30 10:38:06.052 18708-14350/? I/EventLogService: Aggregate from 1462028885536 (log), 1462028885536 (data)

04-30 10:38:06.060 2173-14351/? E/AppUsageEventWatcher: unexpected event type: 7

04-30 10:38:06.060 2173-14351/? E/AppUsageEventWatcher: unexpected event type: 7

04-30 10:38:06.160 18708-14350/? I/ServiceDumpSys: dumping service [account]

04-30 10:38:19.735 799-9537/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=961740548, 192.168.0.1, [2A3044130F46], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}

04-30 10:38:24.745 799-9537/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=961745558, 192.168.0.1, [2A3044130F46], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_PROBE}

04-30 10:38:27.879 799-1199/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 109]

04-30 10:38:30.887 799-1199/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 109]

04-30 10:38:31.783 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: TM Id 'SKIN_THERMAL_management_1' Sensor 'xo_therm_pu2' - alarm raised 1 at 40.0 degC

04-30 10:38:31.784 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[0] to 1958400

04-30 10:38:31.784 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[1] to 1958400

04-30 10:38:31.784 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[2] to 1958400

04-30 10:38:31.784 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[3] to 1958400

04-30 10:38:31.784 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: LCD - Setting max LCD brightness to 229

04-30 10:38:38.655 799-9537/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=961759468, 192.168.0.1, [2A3044130F46], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}

04-30 10:38:43.665 799-9537/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=961764478, 192.168.0.1, [2A3044130F46], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_PROBE}

04-30 10:38:47.962 1855-13559/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator.LanguageModelFlusher: run()

04-30 10:38:47.967 1855-13559/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: flushDynamicLanguageModels()

04-30 10:38:48.010 2173-2173/? I/ConfigService: onCreate

04-30 10:38:48.021 799-812/? I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 17ms

04-30 10:38:48.340 799-811/? I/ProcessStatsService: Pruning old procstats: /data/system/procstats/state-2016-04-27-03-31-36.bin

04-30 10:38:53.117 2173-2173/? I/ConfigService: onDestroy

04-30 10:38:57.575 799-9537/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=961778388, 192.168.0.1, [2A3044130F46], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}

04-30 10:39:01.812 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: TM Id 'battery_LCD_monitor' Sensor 'batt_therm' - alarm raised 2 at 340.0 degC

04-30 10:39:01.812 206-276/? E/ThermalEngine: override action 7500

04-30 10:39:01.812 206-276/? E/ThermalEngine: Thermal-Server: Thermal received msg override 7500

04-30 10:39:01.812 206-276/? E/ThermalEngine: override_notify : SS mode 1 override 7500

04-30 10:39:02.585 799-9537/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=961783398, 192.168.0.1, [2A3044130F46], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_REACHABLE}

04-30 10:39:03.975 799-1199/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 109]

04-30 10:39:06.985 799-1199/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 109]

04-30 10:39:11.830 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: TM Id 'SKIN_THERMAL_management_1' Sensor 'xo_therm_pu2' - alarm raised 2 at 42.0 degC

04-30 10:39:11.831 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[0] to 1574400

04-30 10:39:11.831 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[1] to 1574400

04-30 10:39:11.831 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[2] to 1574400

04-30 10:39:11.831 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[3] to 1574400

04-30 10:39:11.831 206-276/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: LCD - Setting max LCD brightness to 204

04-30 10:39:15.850 14204-14232/? I/Unity: success



  (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

04-30 10:39:18.335 799-9537/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=961799148, 192.168.0.1, [2A3044130F46], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}

04-30 10:39:18.820 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()

04-30 10:39:18.965 1855-1855/? D/KeyboardTheme: No property defined for ro.com.google.ime.theme_id

04-30 10:39:19.026 1855-1855/? W/RichInputMethodSubtype: Can't find emoji subtype

04-30 10:39:19.026 1855-1855/? W/RichInputMethodSubtype: No input method subtype found; returning dummy subtype: Multi-lingual subtype: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSubtype@d78b2ed0, zz

04-30 10:39:19.190 1855-1855/? I/EmojiCategory: Last Emoji category id is 8

04-30 10:39:19.206 1855-1855/? W/ViewPager: Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1

04-30 10:39:19.209 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onStartInput()

04-30 10:39:19.219 1855-1855/? D/KeyboardTheme: No property defined for ro.com.google.ime.theme_id

04-30 10:39:19.219 1855-1855/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0

04-30 10:39:19.233 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: resetDictionaries() : no-op

04-30 10:39:19.233 1855-1855/? I/StatsUtilsManager: onLoadSettings()

04-30 10:39:20.342 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onStartInput()

04-30 10:39:20.353 1855-1855/? D/KeyboardTheme: No property defined for ro.com.google.ime.theme_id

04-30 10:39:20.353 1855-1855/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 1,1

04-30 10:39:20.358 1855-16807/? I/Spelling.Facilitator: resetDictionaries() : en_US

04-30 10:39:20.358 1855-16807/? I/Spelling.Personal: create()

04-30 10:39:20.362 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.DecoderInitializer: run()

04-30 10:39:20.362 1855-14676/? I/Decoder: createOrResetDecoder

04-30 10:39:20.377 2173-2173/? I/ConfigService: onCreate

04-30 10:39:20.442 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.MainLanguageModelLoader: run()

04-30 10:39:20.637 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.MainLanguageModelLoader: loadStaticLm() : Loading File = /data/user/0/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/files/dicts/en_US/main%00003aen_us (offset=0, length=4430832) with up to date LoudsLmContentVersion = 20160111

04-30 10:39:20.642 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.DynamicLanguageModelLoader: run()

04-30 10:39:20.642 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.DynamicLanguageModelLoader: run() : Loading LM = contacts

04-30 10:39:20.648 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.DynamicLanguageModelLoader: run() : Loaded File = Contacts.dict

04-30 10:39:20.648 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.DynamicLanguageModelLoader: run() : Loading LM = user

04-30 10:39:20.650 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.DynamicLanguageModelLoader: run() : Missing File = Personal.en_US.dict

04-30 10:39:20.650 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Facilitator.PersonalDictionaryLoader: run() : Loading Personal Dictionary

04-30 10:39:20.650 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Personal: open()

04-30 10:39:20.650 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Personal: loadPersonalDictionary() : Start Loading

04-30 10:39:20.671 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Personal: loadPersonalDictionary() : Empty

04-30 10:39:20.672 1855-14676/? I/Spelling.Personal: loadPersonalDictionary() : Loaded 0 words and 0 shortcuts

04-30 10:39:22.818 1855-1855/? I/Spelling.Facilitator: closeDictionaries()

04-30 10:39:22.818 1855-1855/? I/Spelling.Facilitator: flushDynamicLanguageModels()

04-30 10:39:22.821 1855-1855/? I/Decoder: createOrResetDecoder

04-30 10:39:22.858 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()

04-30 10:39:22.968 189-189/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.

04-30 10:39:23.771 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()

04-30 10:39:23.773 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onStartInput()

04-30 10:39:23.779 1855-1855/? D/KeyboardTheme: No property defined for ro.com.google.ime.theme_id

04-30 10:39:23.779 1855-1855/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,4

04-30 10:39:23.810 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: resetDictionaries() : no-op

04-30 10:39:23.810 1855-1855/? I/StatsUtilsManager: onLoadSettings()

04-30 10:39:25.476 2173-2173/? I/ConfigService: onDestroy

04-30 10:39:26.981 14204-14204/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

04-30 10:39:26.984 1855-1855/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.

04-30 10:39:26.984 1855-1855/? W/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor. Setting caps mode without knowing text.

04-30 10:39:27.024 1855-437/? D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xaa774800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9eb4b5b0

04-30 10:39:27.053 1855-1855/? I/Spelling.Facilitator: closeDictionaries()

04-30 10:39:27.053 1855-1855/? I/Spelling.Facilitator: flushDynamicLanguageModels()

04-30 10:39:27.053 1855-1855/? I/Decoder: createOrResetDecoder

04-30 10:39:27.069 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()

04-30 10:39:27.183 189-189/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.

04-30 10:39:28.480 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()

04-30 10:39:28.481 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onStartInput()

04-30 10:39:28.488 1855-1855/? D/KeyboardTheme: No property defined for ro.com.google.ime.theme_id

04-30 10:39:28.488 1855-1855/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0

04-30 10:39:28.544 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: resetDictionaries() : no-op

04-30 10:39:28.544 1855-1855/? I/StatsUtilsManager: onLoadSettings()

04-30 10:39:30.393 14204-14204/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

04-30 10:39:30.393 1855-1855/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.

04-30 10:39:30.393 1855-1855/? W/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor. Setting caps mode without knowing text.

04-30 10:39:30.449 1855-1855/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()

04-30 10:39:30.602 189-189/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.

04-30 10:39:35.483 1855-1863/? W/CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()

04-30 10:39:35.965 14204-14232/? I/Unity: Spawning 13 pages



  (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

04-30 10:39:37.111 799-1199/? D/ConnectivityService: updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 109] to 56

04-30 10:39:37.806 14204-14232/? I/Unity: BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase



  (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

04-30 10:39:38.696 2173-2988/? I/ClearcutLoggerApiImpl: disconnect managed GoogleApiClient

04-30 10:39:39.590 14204-14232/? I/Unity: BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase



   (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

04-30 10:39:41.446 14204-14232/? I/Unity: BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase



  (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

04-30 10:39:43.144 799-1199/? D/ConnectivityService: updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 109] to 60
```

**EDIT:** Not helping you guys help me if you cannot see the code. Here you can see the mildly modified Purchaser.cs: http://pastebin.com/kYTjGU0q

**EDIT2** Ok, for some reason, after adding the store key, only the first item works from this code:

```
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

        for (int i = 1; i < totalAmountOfCourses; i++)
        {
            builder.AddProduct(productUnlockLevel, ProductType.NonConsumable, new IDs()
            {
                { productUnlockLevel, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { (productUnlockLevel).ToLower(), GooglePlay.Name },
            });
        }
        builder.AddProduct(productMonthlySub, ProductType.Subscription, new IDs()
        {
            { productMonthlySub, AppleAppStore.Name },
            { productMonthlySub.ToLower(), GooglePlay.Name },
        });

        builder.Configure<IGooglePlayConfiguration>().SetPublicKey("my key");
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
```

Other items are gathered correctly:
(removed some descriptions with [...])

05-05 18:03:53.529 31881-32046/? I/UnityIAP: Got sku details: SkuDetails:{"productId":"[...]","type":"subs","price":"$6.99","price_amount_micros":6990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","title":"[...]","description":"[...]"}

But won't work when purchased:

05-05 18:05:03.632 31881-31910/? I/Unity: Initialised. Trying to purchase: [...]                                                                                     (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42) 05-05 18:05:03.632 31881-31910/? I/Unity: BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product '[...]', either is not found or is not available for purchase

Comment: Maybe you are missing to upload the app as a alpha test in google developer console ? If you want to test that it's not setup wrong in the editor you can consider using MobiShop  (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636) they give you a simple way of testing the purchase in the editor as well. so you can limit the errors to the setup in google developer console for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase
```

This is the function that is being called in the background.

```
 public void BuySubscription()
    {
        // Buy the subscription product using its the general identifier. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
        BuyProductID(kProductIDSubscription);
    }


    void BuyProductID(string productId)
    {
        // If the stores throw an unexpected exception, use try..catch to protect my logic here.
        try
        {
            // If Purchasing has been initialized ...
            if (IsInitialized())
            {
                // ... look up the Product reference with the general product identifier and the Purchasing system's products collection.
                Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);

                // If the look up found a product for this device's store and that product is ready to be sold ... 
                if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
                {
                    Debug.Log (string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));// ... buy the product. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
                    m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
                }
                // Otherwise ...
                else
                {
                    // ... report the product look-up failure situation  
                    Debug.Log ("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
                }
            }
            // Otherwise ...
            else
            {
                // ... report the fact Purchasing has not succeeded initializing yet. Consider waiting longer or retrying initiailization.
                Debug.Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
            }
        }
        // Complete the unexpected exception handling ...
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ... by reporting any unexpected exception for later diagnosis.
            Debug.Log ("BuyProductID: FAIL. Exception during purchase. " + e);
        }
    }
```

So this means that `Product` is either null or `Product.availableToPurchase` returns false. Right now, I think that the problem is `Product.availableToPurchase`.

According to the API [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Purchasing.Product-availableToPurchase.html), `Product.availableToPurchase` will be `false` if the product's identifier is **unknown**, **incorrect** or otherwise **disabled** with the store provider (ie Apple, Google et al).

So make sure that your identifier  is correct and also not disabled with the store provider. I have no no idea what the store provider means but it probably means enabling in-app purchase in Android settings.

Comment: - It is known (specified during init).

- It is correct, as it was triple-checked with the productID on Google Play.

- Is it enabled, as I'm testing via the published alpha.

- I really don't know what it could be...

Comment: @InsaneGoblin Can you test in another Android device and see if you will get the-same thing?

Comment: Tried on three, unfortunately, same issue. All 3 are rooted with different ISOs

Comment: @InsaneGoblin Try on a phone that was not rooted/modified in any way.

Comment: I think that you can setup a list of developers that have access to in-app purchase in alpha versions on android. This is somewhere in your account settings in the android console. I think you have to enable this before being able to test your IAP

Comment: Also did that. Tried on secondary accounts, alpha and beta. Added the modified purchaser code in the quesiton, in case I messed up badly

Comment: @InsaneGoblin The code you posted, why are you always converting stuff to `.ToLower()` for Android and but for iOS. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @Programmer, on Android, productIDs are in lowercase. Cannot remember where I read this, but considering that the iOS and Android IDs are the same with just the case difference, I did the ToLower()

Comment: @InsaneGoblin Ok. You said you published it, did you upload the apk? Make sure that the published APK bundle version is the-same as the one you will be testing with. Read this post and tell me if that helps http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/purchases-not-processing-on-android.374916/

Comment: Definitely published: http://prntscr.com/azvrrr with products online: http://prntscr.com/azvry3

Comment: @InsaneGoblin Running out of ideas. This is a pain. Did you enter your Google API key?

Comment: It's a pain for me as well. Been fighting this for 2 months. What API key and where?

Answer (score 0):

When I created a product in GooglePlayConsole and immediately tried to test the purchase, I had the same error. And when I tried it the next day, it was gone. So it is worth considering that the changes made to the GooglePlayConsole will not be displayed immediately. I think sometimes it can take a couple of hours.